# Python Tkinter message box with multiple text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM0jq.png
How can I make the text on the right hand side(*stored in variable* **msg2**) to start from the top, ie same horizontal level as message on left hand side(**msg**)
Here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
msg = """I very soon decided that until I had done something towards naming and describing the most important groups in my collection, and had worked out some of the more interesting problems of variation and geographical distribution (of which I had had glimpses while collecting them), I would not attempt to publish my travels.GoodBye!!"""
w= Message(top,text=msg)
msg2="""I feel bound to give them full satisfaction on this point"""
v= Message(top,text=msg2)
w.grid(row=0,column=0)
v.grid(column=1,row=0)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sticky` option (See [`grid` documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)):

```
w.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
v.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
```